# My Google Search results used to include a “Translate this page” link alongside each search result

Tags: google-search, google-translate

This does not appear now and I have tried to find a way to bring back that option for many hours today until I am totally frustrated. I did however find some information on the web that suggests the option is still available:

> Your results may include a “Translate this page” link when a results page is written in a language different from your interface language

How can I bring this option back to my devices?

Comment: To "your devices"? As far as I know this was only ever available in the desktop browser.

Comment: For what it's worth, Google often makes changes to its services and the help pages don't keep up.

Comment: From a tablet or mobile make sure you are using the Desktop view to see this option, or you can install the Google Translate app (on Android) and use Share link from the browser (alternatively, just install Dolphin's browser).